# MySQL insert always inserts defaults

Tags: mysql, kumulos

Im trying to run this query

```
("INSERT INTO units SET id="+toID+" AND num="+number+" AND unit_id="+type+"")
```

this is the log

```
[2014-05-13 13:09:51] Running query: INSERT INTO units SET id=3 AND num=10 AND unit_id=1
```

these values are never inserted, it defaults to 0. It only happens on insert queries, i can select fine.

It inserts fine from a php script, however im using Kumulos KScript to run these queries, all have worked fine apart from this one.

Is there a setting on the table that i have missed or something?

Any suggestions?

Many Thanks,
Paul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a correct `INSERT` query.

Try this:

```
("INSERT INTO units(id, num, unit_id) VALUES ("+toID+", "+number+", "+type+")")
```

Answer (score 2):

`INSERT INTO` with `SET` in `MYSQL` does not need AND as you have

The correct syntax is

```
INSERT INTO table
SET
       col1 = 'val1',
       col2 = 'val2',
       col3 = 'val3'
```

OR You can use the following

```
INSERT INTO table
     ( col1, col2, col3 )
VALUES 
     ( 'val1', 'val2', 'val3' )
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
INSERT INTO units ( id, num, unit_id ) VALUES ( toID, number, type )
```

Or:

```
INSERT INTO units id=toID, num=number, unit_id=type
```